# Nifi User addition gives u null pointer exception

Tags: apache-nifi

In the Nufi UI user addition page , i am getting

```
 o.a.nifi.web.api.config.ThrowableMapper An unexpected error has occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException. Returning Internal Server Error response.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.nifi.web.dao.impl.StandardPolicyBasedAuthorizerDAO.lambda$null$2(StandardPolicyBasedAuthorizerDAO.java:285)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:174)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1553)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of NiFi are you running? I believe this was addressed here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6020

Comment: Is there anyway to identify which group need to be deleted from authorization.xml. means how the group id is linked here ?

Comment: the AD group name present in authorizers.xml file, how the AD group name is mapped to the   unique id (group identifier) in policy identifier tag in authozations.xml file.